# How to set php xdebug flag in ActionScript?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, debugging, xdebug, remote-debugging

My server runs PHP, with xdebug enabled. I am remotely debugging php code through PhpStorm.

then how to set php xdebug flag in ActionScript?

In iOS code, it is simple:
[pairs addObject:@"XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM"];

But how to do similar thing in ActionScript?

FYI:
http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer to your actual question, so that future users can find it easily.  Please see the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add debug session flag as part of query string in your server URL: www.abc.com/xyz.php??XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM